# 'no such command: '$eval'' on server localhost:27017

Tags: mongodb

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongeez' defined in class path resource [com/niyo/admin/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mongeez.MongeezRunner]: Factory method 'mongeez' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 59 (CommandNotFound): 'no such command: '$eval'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "no such command: '$eval'", "code": 59, "codeName": "CommandNotFound"}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at com.niyo.admin.Application.main(Application.java:115)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mongeez.MongeezRunner]: Factory method 'mongeez' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 59 (CommandNotFound): 'no such command: '$eval'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "no such command: '$eval'", "code": 59, "codeName": "CommandNotFound"}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 59 (CommandNotFound): 'no such command: '$eval'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "no such command: '$eval'", "code": 59, "codeName": "CommandNotFound"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:303)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:259)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:450)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:218)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:343)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:324)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.access$100(CommandOperationHelper.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper$7.call(CommandOperationHelper.java:302)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withReleasableConnection(OperationHelper.java:501)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:298)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:272)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:262)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandWriteOperation.execute(CommandWriteOperation.java:56)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:206)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:175)
    at com.mongodb.DB.executeCommand(DB.java:770)
    at com.mongodb.DB.doEval(DB.java:597)
    at com.mongodb.DB.eval(DB.java:613)
    at org.mongeez.dao.MongeezDao.runScript(MongeezDao.java:135)
    at org.mongeez.commands.Script.run(Script.java:32)
    at org.mongeez.ChangeSetExecutor.execute(ChangeSetExecutor.java:60)
    at org.mongeez.ChangeSetExecutor.execute(ChangeSetExecutor.java:45)
    at org.mongeez.Mongeez.process(Mongeez.java:45)
    at org.mongeez.MongeezRunner.execute(MongeezRunner.java:72)
    at com.niyo.admin.config.DatabaseConfiguration.getMongeez(DatabaseConfiguration.java:138)
    at com.niyo.admin.config.DatabaseConfiguration.mongeez(DatabaseConfiguration.java:125)
    at com.niyo.admin.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f4c08bf.CGLIB$mongeez$6(<generated>)
    at com.niyo.admin.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f4c08bf$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$53afd605.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.niyo.admin.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f4c08bf.mongeez(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What is the command you like to run?

Comment: Most likely you hit this one: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/index.html : *Starting in version 4.2, MongoDB removes the eval command. The deprecated db.eval(), which wraps the eval command, can only be run against MongoDB 4.0 or earlier versions.*

Comment: Is there any way to run this command?

Comment: what can be the alternative to run this instead of eval , for eg:- I was trying to run this mdb.runCommand(new Document("$eval", "db.loadServerScripts()")); , but it gave the same error as above

Answer (score 1):

`$eval` is a `db.eval()` command, which is deprecated and removed in new MongoDB versions:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/