# Mongeez with spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have some set of MongoDB insert commands to be executed during the application startup. refered https://github.com/hzpz/mongeez-spring-boot-starter for my requirement 
Followed the below steps

1) Added the dependency in pom

2) Created js and mongeez.xml in an external folder

3) Referred the location in mongeez.location={myDir}/db

I am getting below exception while starting the application

> Caused by:  com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 59 (CommandNotFound): 'no such command: 
>       '$eval'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "no such command: 
>   '$eval'", "code": 59, "codeName": "CommandNotFound"}

The contents of the js file is

> db.organization.save({"Name" : "10Gen", "Location" : "NYC"});

the contents of mongeez.xml is

> ```
> <changeFiles> <file path="config.js"/> </changeFiles>
> ```

Spring Boot Version : 2.2.1.RELEASE 
Mongeez Version : 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The `db.eval()` command is not supported after mongo:4.2 verison.

check this link ['no such command: '$eval'' on server localhost:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59357222/no-such-command-eval-on-server-localhost27017)

Let me know, if you found something, in the mean time we can only go back to mongo:4.0 or start using mongobee https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee